How can I locally change the maxcitenames?
I would like to locally change the maxcitenames arguments around a biblatex citation. I know that according to the documentation (Appendix E), this option generally cannot be changed in the refcontext scope, but I thought maybe it is possible along the lines of this solution for locally disabeling the sortcites option:
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DisableSortcites}{%
  \let\blx@thecitesort\blx@citenosort
  \let\blx@thenotecheck\relax
  \boolfalse{sortcites}}
\makeatother

Here is an MWE to play around:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
maxcitenames=1,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
sorting=ynt,
bibstyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{referenceA,
  author = {Anderson, Alice},
  title = {Generic Article Title A},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2022},
}
@article{referenceB,
  author = {Anderson, Alice and Birch, Bob},
  title = {Generic Article Title B},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2024},
}
@article{referenceC,
  author = {Campbel, Carol and Davidsson, Dave},
  title = {Generic Article Title C},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

    \parencite{referenceA, referenceC}
    \cite{referenceB}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}


Related/duplicate: How do you change how a single citation is displayed?

Thanks @Werner! Unfortunately, a per-entry solution doesn't work in my case, because I only need to change maxcitenames locally for specific parts of my document, whereas an entry-based solution would affect maxcitenames globally.
